# Exchange Api send incorrect invitation in Israel timezone

Tags: api, timezone, exchange-server

I faced to following problem with sending invitation in .net using exchange API

Send invitation in Israel timezone with start time =09/09/2013 4.30 Israel.

But it is displayed in outlook 09/09/2013 6.30 Israel.

It works properly for other time zones for example for EST.

Does anybody has any idea how to fix this?

Sample:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl(loginForm.tbEmailAddress.Text, f);
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Israel Standard Time");

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
appointment.Subject = "subj";
appointment.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, "body");
appointment.StartTimeZone = timeZoneInfo;
appointment.Start = GetDateTime(new DateTime(2013, 09, 09, 04, 0, 0));
appointment.EndTimeZone = timeZoneInfo;
appointment.End = GetDateTime(new DateTime(2013, 09, 09, 04, 30, 0));
appointment.IsAllDayEvent = false;
appointment.Importance = Importance.Normal;
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("Lena", "email...");

appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

...

```
private static DateTime GetDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute,
                        dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond, DateTimeKind.Unspecified
                       );
}
```

I use Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll 15.0.516.14

Comment: That `GetDateTime` method doesn't do anything except set the `Kind` to `Unspecified`, which it already is.  So you can get rid of that.  The rest of your code looks like it should work just fine.  I don't see anything wrong with it.  Can you show a partial screenshot of how it looks in outlook?  Be sure to check the Time Zones button in the toolbar so we can see them in the screenshot.  Also, which versions of Outlook and Exchange are you running?

Comment: It is displayed with 3 different times in outlook: 4-4.30 in subject; 5-5.30 as start time; 6-6.30 on calendar

Comment: image - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5QUmZicFfwgbHN3dlZVZmZuODQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This was reproduced on Exchange 2010 (office 365). Outlook 2010 - 14.0.6129.5000 (64 bit)

Comment: What time zone is your computer set to?

Comment: Version of outlook: 14.0.6129.5000 (64bit). Exchange 2010 (office 365)

Comment: For testing purpose I set it = Jerusalem. (It used to be set = Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga..)

Comment: This issue was fixed for me by installing following update from microsoft - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2794119

Comment: Cool.  Please put that in an answer.  You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually a known issue with Exchange EWS itself. Developer can only trust the date time returned without the timezone information, and the correct timezone for that time should be UTC always.